# needing help in formatting date from jason to angular js

Tags: angularjs

why is that i receive and error and no data are showing when i remove the time in , what i want is just the (example)

```
"DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015" 

$scope.Combination = [    
          {
              "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 07:00"
          },
          {
              "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 10:55"
          },
          {
              "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 12:10"
          },
          {
              "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 16:10"
          },
          {
              "DepartureDateTime": "07/14/2015 22:00"
          }  
      ];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrupausan/dak8h3oh/2/

Comment: if you remove the time in your example all the dates are the same.. so this condition is never true "if (startDate < inputDate && inputDate < endDate)"

Comment: i got it already thanks bro.

Comment: it depends on your logic.. What exactly do you wanna do? if there is no time should the condition be true?

Comment: yes if there is no time still the condition is true

Comment: Please let me know exactly what you want? am not clear to understand your question buddy.

Comment: i already got the problem solve buddy , but i just to ask you a question. What i really wanted to do is get the data from an API the api is in json format and i wanted to get the data from the api by date. I want to get the data from the api which date is today , get the weekly data from the api and so the monthly. all is filtered by date.